# What happens to a Java Web Container's memory when there are too many concurrent sessions?

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver

A question came up at work today:

Imagine that I have a lot of concurrent users accessing my website, each with their own data stored in user sessions.  Considering that I have a limited amount of memory available in my JVM, what happens, or what is supposed to happen, when the concurrent active sessions reach a point where the container JVM runs out of memory?

I tried to find something in the servlet spec about what **should** happen but there is nothing definitive in there, it just says that the developer will have access to the session objects, etc.  This makes me think that it must be provider specific.

Taking Tomcat as an example, does the webserver just start throwing `OutOfMemoryException`s?  Or is it more clever about the way it deals with this, for example paging the sessions off to another cache?  Or another way all together?

Comment: Have your tried opening a load of sessions and finding out? If I remember correctly we did this with jMeter and Websphere and it came to a grinding halt after a while when it ran out of memory

Comment: tomcat is going to serialize some session at the harddrive

Comment: @anfy2002us Tomcat will not serialize any sessions in its default configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The servlet specification does not say anything about memory considerations, so you'll get no help there.

Unless configured specifically to do otherwise, Tomcat will allow you to use-up all available memory with your HttpSession objects (realy, their contents) and ultimately the JVM will start throwing `OutOfMemoryError`s, potentially taking your server down (though the JVM will continue to run, many things will behave ... unpredictably and unfortunately).

If a single request starts using a lot of memory in local variables, etc., the request-processing thread will suffer an `OutOfMemoryError` and stop processing the current request. (I believe in this case, the request-processing thread will actually be recycled by the Tomcat request-processing thread pool). The garbage collector will likely run shortly thereafter and re-claim the memory used by that request and your server will stabilize.

On the other hand, if you use-up a lot of memory and store those objects into the user's `HttpSession`, then the GC cannot free any memory and your server will continuously suffer from `OutOfMemoryError`s. Though Tomcat will expire sessions on a specified schedule (the default is after 30 minutes of inactivity), the session-cleansing thread may encounter an `OutOfMemoryError` during operation and therefore fail to perform its duty, compounding the whole situation (because, effectively, `HttpSession`s will never expire).

There are several ways to mitigate the above unfortunate scenario. Which one makes sense to you is up to your requirements and environment.

1. Increase your heap size. This will obviously only get you so far. If you are filling-up a 16GiB heap with `HttpSession` and related objects, then you are reaching the limits of commodity hardware and you can't simply buy-a-bigger-box.
2. Reduce the session expiration time (default is 30 minutes). If a session isn't explicitly terminated (say, through a logout function), then the `HttpSession` object and all its contents stick around until the expiration interval has passed. If you have lots of data in lots of abandoned sessions, reducing the session expiration time may give you some breathing room.
3. Stop putting so much data into the user's `HttpSession`. While this may seem like an obnoxious suggestion ("stop doing that"), it is honestly a valid one: do you really need to store so much stuff in the session itself? How about using a data store of some kind (relational database, non-relational database like Cassandra, webcache, etc.)? Maybe store the data in a file on the disk? While these suggestions will certainly limit your ability to access your data *quickly*, they are certainly better options than having your server come crashing down under the weight of so much stuff in your session.
4. Use Tomcat's [`PersistentManager`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html), which is a session manager capable of swapping active (but idle) sessions to some external storage (file-based and JDBC-based storage mechanisms are available by default). This can get you a long way while you figure out some other place to put all that data you are shoving into the user's session.

All but #4 are applicable to any servlet container. #4 should be available to JBoss users, as JBoss uses Tomcat internally. For other containers, you may find that a similar capability exists.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is vendor dependent.  It is, however, frequent that containers can serialize sessions to disk at its discretion (*if* the session data can be serialized).

If the container can do this, it can push out inactive sessions when needed and restore them again when needed, using memory better and thereby postponing any OutOfMemoryExceptions.